# How do I use a main query value as a filter in a Subquery in cake php

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

How do I translate this into orm that uses the value form the main query in the sub query 
Here is my sql subquery

```
(select ups.username from users as ups where ups.id=student_id) as StudentName
```

My main query gets the `student_id` from an inner join
Here is my Orm Subquery

```
    ->select([
        'StudentName'=>'Users.username'])
    ->where(['Users.id'=>'students.studentid']);
```

When I run the query `StudentName` shows up blank, but if I manually set the value like this it returns a result

```
    ->select([
        'StudentName'=>'Users.username'])
    ->where(['Users.id'=>'55']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `key => value` syntax, the right hand side value will always be subject to binding/escaping, unless it's an expression object. So your condition will bind `Students.student_id` as a literal string, or possibly as an integer, ie you end up with SQL like:

```sql
WHERE Users.id = 'Students.student_id'
```

or

```sql
WHERE Users.id = 0
```

Either pass a `\Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression` object, like:

```php
->where(['Users.id' => $mainQuery->identifier('Students.student_id')])
```

or in older CakePHP versions:

```php
->where(['Users.id' => new \Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('Students.student_id')])
```

Or use the expression builder, which has support for comparing fields:

```php
->where(function(\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) {
    return $exp->equalFields('Users.id', 'Students.student_id');
})
```

There's an example for your use case in the advanced conditions docs (see the `exists()` example).

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**